# Apply formula on condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'd like to add a condition to one of my Excel formulas. In Cell C1 I have a formula like this : `= A1 +B1` but if cell A1 is empty but cell B1 does contain a value (or vice versa) I'd like cell C1 to stay empty.

Condition : Only apply formula if both cells contain any value.

(The formula I'm using in cell C1 calculates the difference between dates, and does this for a list of values, so it is applied on the whole range "C:C".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

```
  =IF(OR(A1="",B1=""),"",A1+B1)
```

Answer (score 1):

**=IF(SUM(IF(A1="",0,1),IF(B1="",0,1))<2,"",A1+B1)**